# Where are the PDB? How to investigate a crash DMP?

Tags: wix, crash-dumps, pdb-files, wix3.6

I have a Wix 3.6 managed bootstrapper installer that crashed on a user machine.  I have the crash DMP file provided by the user, but I can't find any PDB files for installer exe.

When I open the DMP file in visual studio 2010, it does not find the symbols.  I am guessing the symbols should come from burn.pdb and my own managed code (which I have the pdb), but I can't have them loaded.

Visual Studio is looking for burn.pdb, but this file is not in the SDK.

How can I debug it?

Comment: right-click on the wix project, select Properties, and uncheck "Suppress output of the wixpdb files".  As for using that to debug the crash, I have no idea.  Usually in these cases I just use windows installer loggin.

Comment: As I understand, the wixpdb are not PDB.  (not sure why they named it like this, it's confusing).  The wixpdb are XML files describing the content of the packages.  They are not designed to be used by a debugger.

Comment: Eh.  Said I never tried to debug a wix project (that's why it was a comment and not an answer).  I've *assumed* that they are used to debug them *somehow*.  Perhaps one of the many executables that come with wix...